# How to make customised android button shown in the below image?

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, button, uibutton

By using css or jquery it's easy to bring this grouped buttons. But in android native application how to design a xml file to bring grouped buttons like this, without using tabWidget method (i.e)tab layout.
[image]

Comment: for making this view you need 3 different images for default, title and Date . If you have these 3 images then its very simple to make this view.

Comment: It's not good i think bcoz i need it inside a popup box, if we use image it's look and feel will change...Is there any idea by using only a buttons?

Comment: we can set the images in imagebutton, and i am sure thats look and feel never changed.

Comment: But how it's possible without using button?

Comment: Using Image Buttons .. but if you have images . .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a segmented radio button. There are various solutions but this is a good one: https://github.com/makeramen/android-segmentedradiobutton